# Using PHP and SQL Server 2005, can I return data from an XML field and convert to a string?

Tags: php, xml, sql-server-2005

I have a SQL Server 2005 table which has XML snippets in an xml column. To properly use XSL to convert the snippets to XHTML, I need to surround the snippet with additional nodes, etc. My thought is that I need to be able to handle the XML data as a string, then I can prepend and postpend to it and then convert to a DOM object.

Is this the right way to go? Is there a better way?

Here is an example of where I need to put the snippet (which can be fairly large):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://www.accessdata.fda.gov/spl/schema/spl.xsd">
    <id />
    <code />
    <effectiveTime  />
    <component>
        <structuredBody>
            << SNIPPET GOES HERE >>
        </structuredBody>
    </component>
</document>
```

Comment: Presumably, the data type for the column is already `varchar` or something similar, so what's the problem? There's no need to convert it to a string because it already is a string, surely?

Comment: No, the field is xml, not varchar. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that Transact SQL will handle the conversion using CAST.

To get the xml data out of an xml field one can use the following:

```
SELECT CAST(XmlField as varchar(max)) AS XmlStr 
FROM table1
WHERE (id = 22234) AND (code = '34071-1')
```

This returned the data as a string, which is what I needed.